# loop produces correct answer in terminal but not when transferred to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The code

```
import pandas as pd 

Ticklist = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = Ticklist.values.ravel()

Individualreport = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Individualreport, engine='xlsxwriter')

row_tick = 0
col_tick = 0

for i in stocks:
    #write ticker in excel
    s = Ticklist.loc[(Ticklist[0]==i)]
    print(s)
    s.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow= row_tick, startcol=row_tick, header=False, index=False)
    row_tick += 47

writer.save()
```

produces in the terminal bc of the print(s)

```
      0
0  ADVM
      0
1  AERI
      0
2  AGTC
     0
3  ALC
      0
4  ALDX
      0
5  ALIM
      0
6  ARPO
      0
7  CLSD
     0
8  COO
      0
9  EYEG
       0
10  EYEN
       0
11  EYPT
       0
12  GKOS
       0
13  ISEE
       0
14  KALA
      0
15  KOD
       0
16  OCUL
       0
17  OTLK
       0
18  STAA
```

but in the "IndividualReport" excel workbook it only writes the first value.
I am wondering if its not working because stocks pulls off of Ticklist??  How could I fix this.  I just want to put the ticker names from the Ticklist/stocks into the Individualreport, each seperated 47 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your error happens because you are re-writing to excel every time you loop through a new stock. This will replace the old file you had with a new one.

You could try something like the below

```py
out = pd.DataFrame()  # create an output dataframe for storing the 's' values
for i in stocks:
    #write ticker in excel
    s = Ticklist.loc[(Ticklist[0]==i)]
    out = out.append(s.copy())  # Append the s row to the final dataframe that we save to excel
    print(s)
out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=0, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: That seems to just write the list without skipping rows

Comment: I guess you could append some empty rows to the dataframe to solve this easily - It should also be possible with the startrow argument, I just haven't been able to make that work myself.

Comment: It looks like i just had a silly mistake in my code and i accidentally wrote the row where the column should be.  Thanks for the help! =)